# How to automate validating omniture events for Mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, adobe-analytics, charles-proxy

I have an iOS and android app that fires omniture events. I am capturing those events through Charles Proxy and validating those events manually. It will take lot of time to validate manually. Are there any way to automatically validate omniture events? it will probably help me to save lot of time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Having integrated Omniture into an Android app before, I feel your pain.

Adobe have a tool that you can use called Bloodhound that acts as a fake Omniture server.

Whilst it won't help in automation, it'll help with debugging because it breaks down the evals, vars & events for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add some object as an abstraction layer between ADMS_Measurement and your application, it can be used to verify all the events you expect to be send in tests (you would need to have tests for this solution). Alternatively you could try to mock ADMS_Measurement object but I never tried this approach. Given the object is structured like this

```
@implementation OmnitureWrapper ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) ADMS_Measurement *admsMeasurement;

- (void)track:(NSDictionary *)trackingVars {
    [self setupVariables:trackingVars];
    [self.admsMeasurement track];
}

@end
```

In tests you can create a mock of OmnitureLayer and make it expect call to -(void)track:(NSDictionary *)trackingVars and verify if the parameters were as expected. For example using OCMock:

```
- (void)testActionXShouldSendOmnitureEventsY {
    id omnitureMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[OmnitureWrapper class]];
    [omnitureMock expect] track:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj) {
        NSDictionary *trackingVars = (NSDictionary *)obj;
        //TODO check if all vars are as expected
    }];

    //TODO actual test code

    [omnitureMock verify];
}
```

You need to write tests for each event that will cause Omniture tracking and then verify if it was correctly called, but if this is important to you it may pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way I have found is to cast the event data from Adobe SDK before it is sent a request to file in a temporary directory on device/simulator during the test run. Then your test can access this file and assert its data in your test script.